# How Calling Web Service in HTML/PHP from java use Javascript/AJAX

Tags: javascript, java, php, ajax, web-services

I have simple method service in java eclipse, use database postgresql but, i want to call the method in html php use javascript or ajax? I want to do insert data into database use this service and get data, how can I calling this method in html/php?

this is my Controller

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.bsm.payroll.model.PayrollModel;
import com.bsm.payroll.repository.PayrollRepoSitory;

@RestController
public class PayrollController {

@Autowired
PayrollRepoSitory payrollRepoSitory;

@GetMapping(value="/payroll")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<PayrollModel> getAllPayroll(){
    return payrollRepoSitory.findAll();
}


//yang dipake untuk upload file di db postgresql
@RequestMapping(path ="/coba-payroll-param", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
String savebyparam(@RequestParam("company_id") String company_id, @RequestParam("nama_file") String nama_file) {

    PayrollModel payroll;

    payroll = new PayrollModel();
    payroll.setStatus("0");
    payroll.setNameFile(nama_file);
    payroll.setCompanyId(company_id);
    payroll.setCreationDate(new Date());

    payrollRepoSitory.save(payroll);
    return nama_file+company_id;

    }

    }
```

This is my pom.xml

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang= "en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv= "X-UA-Compatible" content= "ie=edge">
<title> Belajar Dasar Ajax </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Tutorial Ajax</h1>
<div id="hasil"></div>
<button onclick="loadContent()">Load Content</button>

<script>
    function loadContent(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://localhost:8181/payroll";
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status ==200){
                document.getElementById("hasil").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.send();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or you have anything else for calling webservice from java to html/php, because this is my first time use this, and I don't have a picture to call java webservice to html/php

Answer (score 1):

You should consider modifying the server to add the `@CrossOrigin` annotation to prevent browsers from blocking requests from your web app. More details [here in mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and specific to spring [in this spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/).

NB. there are additional options to this annotation which could add further security or indicate how you would like browser based applications to interact with your server.

The updated code for your java rest controller would look something like this:

```
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    import com.bsm.payroll.model.PayrollModel;
    import com.bsm.payroll.repository.PayrollRepoSitory;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
    
    @CrossOrigin
    @RestController
    public class PayrollController {
    
    @Autowired
    PayrollRepoSitory payrollRepoSitory;
```

Your code above is ONE way to get the data, there are many tools/frameworks/libraries however I will respond using your implementation below.

#### Retrieving content

```
<script>
    function loadContent(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://localhost:8181/payroll";
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status ==200){
                var dataAsString = this.responseText; //this is a string
                //your method seems to return a list of payrol items/objects
                //you may be interested in displaying each of these as such
                //you should parse the JSON (usual default) data returned from the 
                //server into an object, 
                var data = JSON.parse(dataAsString);
                //now you should have an array or payrol items.
                //Let's say that you would like to display a list of "name" s
                document.getElementById("hasil").innerHTML = '';
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    document.getElementById("hasil").innerHTML +='<p>'+data[i].name+'</p>' ;
                }
                
            }
        };
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.send();
    }
</script>
```

#### Saving content

I noticed that you are posting content which is good when considering restful conventions. In another iteration you may consider passing data using the `@RequestBody` [see more details here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body) . However with your implementation, a method that could save data to your server may look like this:

```
<script>
    function saveCobaPayrollParam(companyId, nameFile){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        //we will pass data using the query string
        //NB how we have a question sign (?) separating the url and the data
        //the data is represented as a set of key=value pairs and separated 
        //by an ampersand
        var url = "http://localhost:8181/coba-payroll-param?company_id="+companyId+"&nama_file="+nameFile;
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status ==200){
                var dataAsString = this.responseText; //this is a string
                //you could provide additional confirmation here eg.
                alert("This operation was successful")
                
            }
        };
        //NB I have changed the request method from GET to POST
        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.send();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `XHR` request coming from across domain, probably your request blocking by browser's `CORS Policy`.

You should enable `CORS` in your spring application with `@CrossOrigin` annotation, also you can enable `CORS` in your entire application with implementing `WebMvcConfigurer`

check this [out](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) tutorial.

You can get detailed information about `CORS` from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)